# Intuition/motivation behind t-cyclic subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

I am having trouble understanding $T$-cyclic subspaces. My textbook gives the following definition:

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$, and let $x$ be a nonzero vector in $V$. The subspace:
$$W = span([x,T(x),T^2(x),...])$$
is called the $T$-cyclic subspace of $V$ generated by $x$.

I am having trouble understanding what this means and the motivation behind such a definition. Once again in linear algebra I find myself wondering: "who cares?" If anyone could provide any intuition or motivation behind this definition that would be awesome. Or even any kind of application of this definition.

Thank you!

Comment: Actually, "who cares" applies already to "subspace". So if you find a subspace useful now, then a cyclic one is a very nice and special one. Otherwise really, who cares.

Comment: One application is the cyclic decomposition Theorem, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subspace) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233811/when-does-a-matrix-have-a-cyclic-decomposition-and-when-a-rational-form) for example.

Comment: Another application is that every bounded operator on a non-separable Banach space has an invariant subspace, thus limiting the study of the [invariant subspace problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem):  The closure of any $T$-cyclic subspace is a proper subspace invariant under $T$.

Comment: There are going to be places in the book where they use the phrase "$T$-cyclic", otherwise they wouldn't give the definition. Those places in the book are applications of the concept.

Comment: @Aweygan Proper? No. (The existence of $T$-cyclic subspaces shows that they need not be proper: Say $V$ is a $T$-cyclic subspace. Let $S$ be the restriction of $T$ to $V$. Then $V$ is an improper $S$-cyclic subspace of $V$.)

Comment: @Aweygan I missed the non-separable, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The cyclic subspaces are very useful for one thing: they are subspaces that are invariant with respect to $T$! That means if $x\in W$, $f(T)x \in W$, where $f$ is a polynomial.

Other useful examples of T-invariant subspaces include $KerT$, $ImT$. Hope this helps!